# Primary key in nested structure on clickhouse database

Tags: nested, primary-key, clickhouse

In clickhouse I have created a table with a nested structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
    timestamp Date,
    str_1 String,
    Nested_structure Nested (
        index_array UInt32,
        metric_2 UInt64,
        metric_3 UInt8
    ),
    sign Int8 DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(timestamp)) ORDER BY (timestamp, str_1)
```

The queries that I will make are like:

```
 SELECT count(*) AS count FROM table_name
 WHERE (timestamp = '2017-09-01')
 AND
 arrayFirst((i, x) -> x = 7151, Nested_structure.metric_2, Nested_structure.index_array) > 50000
```

I want to count **str_1** where:
value of (array) column  **metric_2** in index matched from **indexed_array** for value 7151, is greater than a given threshold (50000)

I was wondering if it is possible to have a primary key for column: ***index_array*** in order to make query faster.

If I add column: **Nested_structure.index_array** in the order by clause it is assumed to be the array column of the large table and not the individual values of the column indexed_array of the Nested_structure

e.g. `ORDER BY (timestamp, str_1, Nested_structure.index_array)`

The algorithm is:

1. Search for the index of a given value in **index_array**
2. Having the index from step (1), retrieve the value from other arrays

If **index_array** is sorted and the table has knowledge of that, then step (1) could be faster (use a binary search algorithm for example)

Someone has an idea?

=============

## **EDIT**

Cardinality of columns:
**str_1** 15,000,000 millions distinct values
**index_array**: 15,000 - 20,000 thousands distinct values

Assuming that index_array distinct values are: column_1, ..., column_15000, then a denormalized table should have the below structure:

```
timestamp,
str_1,
column_1a, <--  store values for metric_2
...
column_15000a, <--  store values for metric_2
column_1b, <--  store values for metric_3
...
column_15000b, <--  store values for metric_3
```

**@Amos** may you give me the structure of the table, if I use a column of type **LowCardinality** ?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it is possible to have a primary key for column: index_array in order to make query faster.

Nope, ClickHouse doesn't have array indices. If you supply `Nested_structure.index_array` as the third argument in the `order by` clause, it will just order the entire row taking into account the array column. Note, `[1,2] < [1,2,3]`.

You can just denormalize the table without the nested column and make the first two columns with type `LowCardinality` which is almost production-ready.

## Update

It seems you won't benefit much from `LowCardinality` types. What I meant was doing something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
    timestamp Date,
    str_1 String,
    index_array UInt32,
    metric_2 UInt64,
    metric_3 UInt8,
    sign Int8 DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(timestamp)) ORDER BY (timestamp, str_1, index_array)
```

And you can still use the old insertion logic by doing this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name ( timestamp Date, str_1 String, index_array UInt32, metric_2 UInt64, metric_3 UInt8, sign Int8 DEFAULT 1 ) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(timestamp)) ORDER BY (timestamp, str_1, index_array)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source_table ( timestamp Date, str_1 String, Nested_structure Nested ( index_array UInt32, metric_2 UInt64, metric_3 UInt8 ), sign Int8 DEFAULT 1 ) ENGINE Null;

create materialized view data_pipe to table_name as select timestamp, str_1, Nested_structure.index_array index_array, Nested_structure.metric_2 metric_2, Nested_structure.metric_3 metric_3, sign from source_table array join Nested_structure;

insert into source_table values (today(), 'fff', [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately columns in nested table (index_array, metric_2, metric_3) have big enough cardinality (~15,000 thousands disticnt values). So I would need more than 10,000 columns in a denormalized table. Btw, where may I find documentation for `LowCardinality` ?

Comment: I meant to apply `LowCardinality` to the first two columns only. Documentation is not available yet. ETA is the end of this year.